# Validate resource references inside android XML files

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, dictionary, fragment

Im getting error while creating map fragment [screen shot of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k84Eh.jpg)

Comment: can I know what type of error you are getting...?

Comment: Validate resource references inside android XML files @RajeshVijayaKumar

Comment: can you paste the bug info from your logcat. So it will help me to identify the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't guess your bug / issue you faced, make sure you followed this minimal configurational steps to create map view in your app...

`Step 1 :`

```
  Import / add google play service library as dependencies in gradle of your android studio project. 
    dependencies {
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' 
   }
```

`Step 2 :`

```
 <fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`Step 3 :`

```
 <!--Permissions-->

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <!--Google MAP API key-->

 <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

`Step 4` :

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thank you  problem solved . Earlier i did't added play services lib to gradle thats why i got that error now solved every thing ..@RajeshVijayakumar